# Installing from outside Nix repository

Tags: package, installation, nix

Can I install some package (using Nix) which is not available in Nix repository but is available as a deb or rpm file or as source (tar.gz)? What is the method to do that? Can this be done only on NixOS or in Nix installed in other linux distributions also? Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 5):

The Nix package manager is a program to manage software. For that, as with all package managers, this software needs to be packaged into a suitable format.

Nix only understands *Nix expressions*, which it uses to build and install software. There are some conversion methods (e.g. for cabal packages), but for most software one needs to have a corresponding Nix expression to be able to use it with Nix.

That said, it is often possible to unpack packages (`.deb` for example) from other package managers. Since most other package managers follow the [*Filesystem Hierarchy Standard* (FHS)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) there's a way to use them with Nix either way:

Using the function `buildFHSUserEnv` one can create an [FHS environment](https://nixos.org/wiki/FHS_environments) containing some Nix packages. To be able to use a `.deb` packaged software with Nix, one must thus:

1. Create a Nix expression to unpack the `.deb` file. The result of this expression is a Nix package with the software, that isn't working because the contained software will look in FHS directories for its dependencies.
2. Create a FHS environment and load the previously build package as well as all dependencies into it.

This is not a trivial procedure, but explained in some depth [here](http://anderspapitto.com/posts/2015-02-28-deb-installation-nixos.html).

Most of the time it is much simpler - if one has access to the source code of the software - to create a normal, "native" Nix package which builds the software in an appropriate way. Creating a package for a standard `./configure`, `make`, `make install` build process is trivial:

```
{ stdenv, fetchurl, autoconf }: # Add other dependencies here, as parameters to the function
stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "FOO-1.42b"; # name of the package
  src = fetchurl { # there's also fetchgit and other helpers
    url = mirror://sourceforge/FOO/FOO-1.42b-src.tar.gz;
    sha256 = "07iwv4j4d2n7f7iffv2xfi1lyp4vr0m9qw40pidw15h1jczxgps9";
  };
  meta = {
    homepage = http://foo.bar;
    description = "bar foo bar foo";
    license = stdenv.lib.licenses.bsd3; # adjust
    platforms = stdenv.lib.platforms.all;
  };
  buildInputs = [ autoconf ]; # just as example, autoconf needed if ...
  preConfigure = "make -f Makefile.aux prepare"; # ... this step of the build hasn't been done upstream yet
  # configureFlags, preBuild, installTargets , ... only if non standard build
}
```

Some documentation about this can be found in the [nixpkgs manual](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#chap-quick-start).

The later method works regardless of whether using Nix alone or within NixOS. For the former, you might get issues if you cannot use Linux namespaces on the base system.